# primefaces: render input type=submit

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.5 and I need a `<input type="submit">`, how I can render this tag from primefaces? I see that primefaces `<p:button .../>` and `<p:commandButton .../>` render `<button type="button" />` but this not work for I want to do in my project, I accept jsf2 too, but I need ajax submit, someone know how to render input type submit and ajax with p:someComponent or h:someComponent ?

Comment: You're under some kind of misconception here: `<p:commandButton/>` by default generates a `submit` type button and the only way to get it to do otherwise is to explicitly set `type=button` on the component

Comment: a submit type button not work for I want to do in my project, I need a input type submit

Answer (score 1):

The standard `<h:commandButton type="submit"/>` renders as `<input type="submit">`, but as far as I'm aware none of the Primefaces components do. Of course you'll lose the themeroller look and feel, so you'd need to add the appropriate `ui-` styles manually (otherwise it's going to look pretty out of place!).

Comment: I'm going to use it and I'm going to set ui styles how you suggest